# QDataStream QIODevice memory allocation

Tags: c++, qt

Say I have a function that creates a QIODevice (e.g. a QFile), then returns a pointer to a QDataStream constructed from the QIODevice. What is the best way to deal with the memory allocation here? Clearly the QIODevice must be heap allocated to stay available to the QDataStream upon function termination, however the destruction of a QDataStream does not destroy or close the device. Is there a standard way of dealing with this seemingly common problem?
Ideally I want a function that returns an object (not a pointer to an object) that behaves like a QDataStream but upon destruction closes the device. Effectively a standard library input stream.

Example code:

```
QDataStream* getStream(const QString& filename) {
  QFile* file = new QFile(filename); // needs to be explicitly deleted later
  file->open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
  QDataStream* out = new QDataStream(&file); // same here
  return out;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
std::shared_ptr<QDataStream> getStream(const QString& filename) 
{
  QFile* file = new QFile(filename); // needs to be explicitly deleted later
  file->open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
  std:shared_ptr<QDataStream> out(new QDataStream(&file), QDSDeleter);
  return out;
}

void QDSDeleter(QDataStream* s)
{
   QIODevice* device = s->device();
   device->close();
   delete device;
}
```

`std::unique_ptr` is another option depending on your needs; [here's a reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) for the former if you need it.

Edit: Qt also has the facility for this with its [QSharedPointer](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsharedpointer.html#details) class, where you can also supply a deleter as a constructor argument. Other pointer wrapper options are given there.  Thanks @RA. for the correction.

Comment: I think you mean QSharedPointer (QScopedPointer can't be copied).

Answer (score 0):

`QDataStream` has a handy `owndev` private member that you can set to true to have the stream effectively own the device. The stream can also be easily made moveable - bringing it very close to your requirement of it behaving like a value. Ideally, you would modify your copy of Qt to implement it, but it can also be worked around.

```
// https://github.com/KubaO/stackoverflown/tree/master/questions/qdatastream-move-own-13039614
#include <QDataStream>

class DataStream : public QDataStream {
   struct Proxy {
      QScopedPointer<QDataStreamPrivate> d;
      QIODevice *dev;
      bool owndev;
      bool noswap;
      QDataStream::ByteOrder byteorder;
      int ver;
      QDataStream::Status q_status;
#if QT_VERSION < QT_VERSION_CHECK(5, 0, 0)
      virtual ~Proxy();
#endif
   };
   static Proxy *p(QDataStream *ds) { return reinterpret_cast<Proxy *>(ds); }
   static const Proxy *p(const QDataStream *ds) {
      return reinterpret_cast<const Proxy *>(ds);
   }
#if defined(QT_TESTLIB_LIB) || defined(QT_MODULE_TEST)
   friend class DataStreamTest;
#endif
  public:
   DataStream() = default;
   using QDataStream::QDataStream;
   DataStream(DataStream &&other) : DataStream(static_cast<QDataStream &&>(other)) {}
   DataStream(QDataStream &&other) {
      using std::swap;
      Proxy &o = *p(&other);
      Proxy &t = *p(this);
      swap(t.d, o.d);
      swap(t.dev, o.dev);
      swap(t.owndev, o.owndev);
      swap(t.noswap, o.noswap);
      swap(t.byteorder, o.byteorder);
      swap(t.ver, o.ver);
      swap(t.q_status, o.q_status);
   }
   DataStream &operator=(DataStream &&other) {
      return *this = static_cast<QDataStream &&>(other);
   }
   DataStream &operator=(QDataStream &&other) {
      this->~DataStream();
      new (this) DataStream(std::move(other));
      return *this;
   }
   void setOwnedDevice(QIODevice *dev) {
      setDevice(dev);
      p(this)->owndev = true;
   }
   bool ownsDevice() const { return p(this)->owndev; }
   static bool ownsDevice(const QDataStream *ds) { return p(ds)->owndev; }
};
```

Since `QObject` has a built-in reference count, we could also have the `QDataStream` act as a shared pointer for it if we wished to.

The following requirements are tested on both Qt 4.8 and 5.10:

```
PASS   : DataStreamTest::isBinaryCompatible()
PASS   : DataStreamTest::streams()
PASS   : DataStreamTest::movesFromNotOwnedQDataStream()
PASS   : DataStreamTest::movesFromNotOwnedDataStream()
PASS   : DataStreamTest::assignsFromNotOwnedQDataStream()
PASS   : DataStreamTest::assignsFromNotOwnedDataStream()
PASS   : DataStreamTest::returnsFromNotOwnedQDataStream()
PASS   : DataStreamTest::returnsFromNotOwnedDataStream()
PASS   : DataStreamTest::movesFromOwnedQDataStream()
PASS   : DataStreamTest::moveFromOwnedDataStream()
PASS   : DataStreamTest::assignsFromOwnedQDataStream()
PASS   : DataStreamTest::assignsFromOwnedDataStream()
PASS   : DataStreamTest::returnsFromOwnedQDataStream()
PASS   : DataStreamTest::returnsFromOwnedDataStream()
```

The test suite follows. The binary compatibility test is extensive and all but excludes the possibility that the UB we depend on is problematic. Note that `QDataStream`'s layout cannot change within the major Qt version - so the above code will work on all future Qt 5 versions.

```
#include <QtTest>

class DataStreamTest : public QObject {
   Q_OBJECT
   static QObjectData *getD(QObject *obj) {
      return static_cast<DataStreamTest *>(obj)->d_ptr.data();
   }
   static bool wasDeleted(QObject *obj) { return getD(obj)->wasDeleted; }
   template <typename T, typename... Args>
   DataStream make_stream(Args &&... args) {
      return T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
   }
   static QDataStream::ByteOrder flipped(QDataStream::ByteOrder o) {
      return (o == QDataStream::BigEndian) ? QDataStream::LittleEndian
                                           : QDataStream::BigEndian;
   }
   Q_SLOT void isBinaryCompatible() {
      QCOMPARE(sizeof(DataStream), sizeof(QDataStream));
      QCOMPARE(sizeof(DataStream::Proxy), sizeof(QDataStream));
      struct Test {
         QByteArray data;
         QDataStream ds{&data, QIODevice::ReadWrite};
         void check(int loc = 0) {
            if (!loc) {
               check(1);
               ds.setDevice(nullptr);
               check(1);
            }
            QCOMPARE(!!ds.device(), DataStream::ownsDevice(&ds));
            QCOMPARE(ds.device(), DataStream::p(&ds)->dev);

            if (!loc) check(2);
            bool noswap = DataStream::p(&ds)->noswap;
            QCOMPARE(noswap, DataStream::p(&ds)->noswap);
            QCOMPARE(ds.byteOrder(), DataStream::p(&ds)->byteorder);
            if (loc != 2) {
               ds.setByteOrder(flipped(ds.byteOrder()));
               noswap = !noswap;
            }
            if (!loc) check(2);
            QCOMPARE(noswap, DataStream::p(&ds)->noswap);

            if (!loc) check(3);
            QCOMPARE(ds.version(), DataStream::p(&ds)->ver);
            if (loc != 3) ds.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_4_0);
            if (!loc) check(3);

            if (!loc) check(4);
            QCOMPARE(ds.status(), DataStream::p(&ds)->q_status);
            if (loc != 4) ds.setStatus(QDataStream::ReadPastEnd);
            if (!loc) check(4);
         }
      } test;
      test.check();
   }
   Q_SLOT void streams() {
      QString str{"Hello, world"};
      QVector<uint> ints{44, 0xDEADBEEF, 1};
      QByteArray data;
      DataStream ds(&data, QIODevice::ReadWrite);
      ds << str << ints;
      ds.device()->reset();
      QString str2;
      QVector<uint> ints2;
      ds >> str2 >> ints2;
      QCOMPARE(str2, str);
      QCOMPARE(ints2, ints);
   }
   Q_SLOT void movesFromNotOwnedQDataStream() {
      QBuffer buf;
      QDataStream ds(&buf);
      QVERIFY(ds.device() == &buf);
      DataStream ds2(std::move(ds));
      QVERIFY(!ds.device());
      QVERIFY(ds2.device() == &buf);
      QVERIFY(!wasDeleted(&buf));
   }
   Q_SLOT void movesFromNotOwnedDataStream() {
      QBuffer buf;
      DataStream ds(&buf);
      QVERIFY(ds.device() == &buf);
      DataStream ds2(std::move(ds));
      QVERIFY(!ds.device());
      QVERIFY(ds2.device() == &buf);
      QVERIFY(!wasDeleted(&buf));
   }
   Q_SLOT void assignsFromNotOwnedQDataStream() {
      QBuffer buf;
      QDataStream ds(&buf);
      QVERIFY(ds.device() == &buf);
      DataStream ds2;
      ds2 = std::move(ds);
      QVERIFY(!ds.device());
      QVERIFY(ds2.device() == &buf);
      QVERIFY(!wasDeleted(&buf));
   }
   Q_SLOT void assignsFromNotOwnedDataStream() {
      QBuffer buf;
      DataStream ds(&buf);
      QVERIFY(ds.device() == &buf);
      DataStream ds2;
      ds2 = std::move(ds);
      QVERIFY(!ds.device());
      QVERIFY(ds2.device() == &buf);
      QVERIFY(!wasDeleted(&buf));
   }
   Q_SLOT void returnsFromNotOwnedQDataStream() {
      QBuffer buf;
      {
         auto ds = make_stream<QDataStream>(&buf);
         QVERIFY(ds.device());
         QVERIFY(!ds.ownsDevice());
      }
      QVERIFY(!wasDeleted(&buf));
   }
   Q_SLOT void returnsFromNotOwnedDataStream() {
      QBuffer buf;
      buf.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite);
      {
         auto ds = make_stream<DataStream>(&buf);
         QVERIFY(ds.device());
         QVERIFY(!ds.ownsDevice());
      }
      QVERIFY(!wasDeleted(&buf));
   }
   Q_SLOT void movesFromOwnedQDataStream() {
      QPointer<QIODevice> buf;
      {
         QByteArray data;
         QDataStream ds(&data, QIODevice::ReadWrite);
         QVERIFY(DataStream::ownsDevice(&ds));
         buf = ds.device();
         DataStream ds2(std::move(ds));
         QVERIFY(!ds.device());
         QVERIFY(ds2.device() == buf);
         QVERIFY(buf);
      }
      QVERIFY(!buf);
   }
   Q_SLOT void moveFromOwnedDataStream() {
      QPointer<QBuffer> buf(new QBuffer);
      {
         DataStream ds;
         ds.setOwnedDevice(buf);
         QVERIFY(ds.device() == buf);
         DataStream ds2(std::move(ds));
         QVERIFY(!ds.device());
         QVERIFY(ds2.device() == buf);
         QVERIFY(buf);
      }
      QVERIFY(!buf);
   }
   Q_SLOT void assignsFromOwnedQDataStream() {
      QPointer<QIODevice> buf;
      {
         QByteArray data;
         QDataStream ds(&data, QIODevice::ReadWrite);
         QVERIFY(DataStream::ownsDevice(&ds));
         buf = ds.device();
         DataStream ds2;
         ds2 = std::move(ds);
         QVERIFY(!ds.device());
         QVERIFY(ds2.device() == buf);
         QVERIFY(buf);
      }
      QVERIFY(!buf);
   }
   Q_SLOT void assignsFromOwnedDataStream() {
      QPointer<QBuffer> buf(new QBuffer);
      {
         DataStream ds;
         ds.setOwnedDevice(buf);
         QVERIFY(ds.device() == buf);
         DataStream ds2;
         ds2 = std::move(ds);
         QVERIFY(!ds.device());
         QVERIFY(ds2.device() == buf);
         QVERIFY(buf);
      }
      QVERIFY(!buf);
   }
   Q_SLOT void returnsFromOwnedQDataStream() {
      QPointer<QIODevice> dev;
      QByteArray data;
      {
         auto ds = make_stream<QDataStream>(&data, QIODevice::ReadWrite);
         dev = ds.device();
         QVERIFY(ds.device());
         QVERIFY(ds.ownsDevice());
      }
      QVERIFY(!dev);
   }
   Q_SLOT void returnsFromOwnedDataStream() {
      QPointer<QIODevice> dev;
      QByteArray data;
      {
         auto ds = make_stream<DataStream>(&data, QIODevice::ReadWrite);
         dev = ds.device();
         QVERIFY(ds.device());
         QVERIFY(ds.ownsDevice());
      }
      QVERIFY(!dev);
   }
};

QTEST_MAIN(DataStreamTest)
#include "main.moc"
```